# Can we use IsDisplayed method in If condition?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have a scenario where, in certain conditions the application crashes and displays an alert "Critical error" occurred. But it occurs rarely. So to handle this I have written a code as

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]")).isDisplayed()){
        System.out.println("Critical Error Occured.");
        driver.close();
    } else {
```

But even when the critical error page is not displayed the if condition is executed and it shows No such element exception. What can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isDisplayed` method in if condition or verify its size to check the element present, that is not an issue, but where you're placing the code matters. The `No such element exception` occurs since the code is verifying at the point where it is placed, and you havn't got the error page, it is throwing an exception

Solution maybe : Place the condition where  page likely to get that error/ where it is necessary

Comment: @Dinu you could use try catch to handle the exceptions, thats a good approach

Answer (score -1):

You should check element exists or not using

```
List<WebElement> criticalError = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"));

if(criticalError.size() >0) {
    System.out.println("Critical Error Occured.");
    driver.close();     
}
else {
    // continue the test
}
```

Comment: This will use default timeout (30s) before stopping finding element. You could adjust the timeout by using driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: only getSize() function is available. I am unable to find .soze function.

Comment: I've just update my answer, getSize() only available with WebElement; size() would be available with List<WebElement> - Since I used findElementS (end with a S)

Comment: @NguyenVuHoang i think the answer you're saying about finding an element present or not is not relevant to the question.

Comment: this is best approach, if error not show -> then go test. As Dinu say, it rarely happens

Comment: @NguyenVuHoang you dont understand. please read the question properly. btw my answer too

Comment: As I understand, an unexpected error **rarely** happens and Dinu want to handle it, if error happens then stop test. The approach to check isDisplayed() may throws NoSuchElementException in case the "unexpected error" doesnot show and you have to use try/catch to handle the exception. That's why I ask to check the error exists or not first. And my approach will never throws any Exception.

Comment: @NguyenVuHoang your approach might not throw any exception thats ok, but thats not what it is all about.